# Internal Server Error while accessing newly installed Ruby on rails ( New App) on localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-mountain-lion

I have completed installation of ROR, Rails.

When I tried starting the server using

```
 rails s

/Users/xyz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:37: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/Cellar in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/xyz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/Cellar in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-09-20 06:19:14] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-09-20 06:19:14] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-05-14) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
[2013-09-20 06:19:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=87245 port=3000
```

I tried accessing localhost:3000 
But following error is appearing-

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Output of brew doctor-

> brew doctor Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with
>   `brew prune`:   /usr/local/bin/unshadow   /usr/local/bin/unique
>   /usr/local/bin/unafs   /usr/local/bin/password.lst
>   /usr/local/bin/mailer   /usr/local/bin/lanman.chr
>   /usr/local/bin/john.conf   /usr/local/bin/john
>   /usr/local/bin/digits.chr   /usr/local/bin/alpha.chr
>   /usr/local/bin/alnum.chr   /usr/local/bin/all.chr
>   /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/john
>
> Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar Leaving kegs unlinked
>   can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to
>   fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
>
> ```
> aircrack-ng
> mysql
> ```
>
> Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew If this a
>   surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications. Stashing
>   returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone should you
>   later need to do so for some reason.
>       cd /usr/local/Library && git stash && git clean -d -f
>
> Warning: Some installed formula are missing dependencies. You should
>   `brew install` the missing dependencies:
>
> ```
> brew install freetype gmp libffi libpng libtool nettle p11-kit
> ```
>
> Run `brew missing` for more details.
>
> Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin This means that
>   system-provided programs will be used instead of those provided by
>   Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
>
> ```
> certtool
> easy_install
> easy_install-2.6
> git
> git-cvsserver
> git-receive-pack
> git-shell
> git-upload-archive
> git-upload-pack
> phar
> phar.phar
> php
> php-config
> phpize
> tclsh
> tclsh8.5
> wish
> wish8.5
> ```
>
> Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin occurs before
>   /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
>       echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile You have new mail in /var/mail/gaurangagrawal

Comment: Have your try turning it off and on again? Just kidding. Can you post the stack trace from your server log please?

Comment: try `brew doctor` and let us know what it says.  the error seems like it's coming from a home brew cellar

Comment: How to find the server log ?@j03w

Comment: @Nikola Please check the new updated question, I added the output of brew doctor there in last part.

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands that brew doctor listed one at a time:

```
brew prune
brew link aircrack-ng
brew link mysql
brew install freetype gmp libffi libpng libtool nettle p11-kit
```

it probably wouldn't hurt to update and upgrade:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Use `brew doctor` again to see what's left.

The last complaint it has has to the with the order the directories in your $PATH are set.  Use the one of off they provided (`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile`) or go in there and take care of it manually.

One more thing, are you using macports?  If so you'll need to remove it, it doesn't play nice with home brew.  Use this link for more infomation: [removing macports, step by step](http://bitboxer.de/2010/06/03/moving-from-macports-to-homebrew/)

Comment: There is this "Internal Server Error"

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. - while accessing localhost:3000 , are you sure this is because of brew ? 
Isn't there some sort of .htaccess file ?

Comment: yes it's totally possible it's something else.  I'm just helping you debug.  I saw the errors came from the cellar so i thought it might originate from home brew.  

did you take care of all the problems brew doctor listed?